# How to print out what function was executed by which worker in ray instead of looking it up on the dashboard?

Tags: python, ray

I am able to see which functions got assigned to which worker on the ray dashboard. Is it possible to print out which function got executed by which worker instead of looking it up on the dashboard?

**Code example:**

```
@ray.remote
def mul1(x):
    return x*x

@ray.remote
def mul2(y):
    return y*y

@ray.remote
def add(x,y):
    return x+y

futures = add.remote(mul1.remote(2), mul2.remote(3))
ray.get(futures)
```

[image]

[image]

**desired output**

```
PID: 2838 - mul2()
PID: 2848 - black()
PID: 2838 - add()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have absolutely no experience with ray, but from pure python side you could write a simple decorator:

```
def print_name(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def deco(*args, **kwargs):
        print(func.__name__)
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return deco
```

Place it under `@ray.remote`

Use example:

```
@ray.remote
@print_name
def my_func():
    pass
```

Comment: I added `@ray.remote` before `def print_name(func)` and called your function and passed one of the functions mentioned in the question using `ray.get(print_name.remote(add))`. The output is `<function ray.remote_function.print_name.<locals>.deco(*args, **kwargs)>`. In order get the output from ray, you have to use `ray.get(insert_function_name_here.remote(pass_variables_here)`. I am not sure if that is how you intended me to use it? Can you please elaborate more on how can I get the output using the function you mentioned?

Comment: @PolarBear10 i've added a use example

Comment: thank you very much! This worked like a charm! Here was my output `(pid=11927) blue
(pid=11928) yellow
(pid=11931) black
(pid=11937) color
(pid=11935) green
(pid=11932) orange
(pid=11928) multiply_matrices_2
(pid=11937) multiply_matrices_1
(pid=11932) multiply_matrices_3
(pid=11937) multi_1
(pid=11932) multi_2
(pid=11932) multi_3` Although not directly related, is there a way to store all the values of the pid's, for example, `pid=11932` in a variable so I am able to group them later to see which pid executed how many functions?